# getting error : Operand should contain 1 column(s). without having inner query on jpa spcification generated query

Tags: mysql, jpa, specifications

i am getting error : Operand should contain 1 column(s)
on jpa specification generated query, on that query there is no subquery its created based join only.
below is a demo of code:

```
select 
    count(studentcla0_.STUDENT_CLASS_SECTION_MAPPING_ID) as col_0_0_ 
from 
    STUDENT_CLASS_SECTION_MAPPING studentcla0_ inner join STUDENT studentdo1_ 
    on studentcla0_.STUDENT=studentdo1_.STUDENT_ID inner join STUDENT studentdo2_ 
    on studentcla0_.STUDENT=studentdo2_.STUDENT_ID cross join USER_CREDENTIALS usercreden3_ 
    cross join USER_CREDENTIALS usercreden4_ 
where 
    studentdo2_.FATHER_CREDENTIAL=usercreden3_.USER_CREDENTIAL_ID 
    and studentdo1_.FATHER_CREDENTIAL=usercreden4_.USER_CREDENTIAL_ID 
    and 
        (usercreden3_.SCHOOL=? 
        and studentcla0_.CLASS=? 
        and studentcla0_.ACADEMIC_YEAR=? 
        and studentcla0_.STUDENT<>
            (? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?) 
        or usercreden4_.SCHOOL=? 
        and studentcla0_.CLASS=? 
        and studentcla0_.ACADEMIC_YEAR=? 
        and studentcla0_.TC_ALLOTED<>? 
        and studentdo1_.STUDENT_STATUS<>? 
        and studentcla0_.STUDENT<>?) 
group by studentcla0_.STUDENT_CLASS_SECTION_MAPPING_ID;
```

i am stuck on this from whole day please someone help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not add more than one value in unequals (<>) use `not in` instead:

```
studentcla0_.STUDENT<> (? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?)
```

must be

```
studentcla0_.STUDENT NOT IN (? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?)
```

Comment: Jens thanks for the answer its right answer i checked in workbench its working if i replace with NOT IN. but problem is that that query is generate by jpa specification and that taking <> instead of NOT IN. any idea how i can implement NOT IN in JPA SPecification?

Comment: @SandeepNishad see https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring/spring-jpa-query-in-clause-example/